# Direct Integration of Client App with Keycloak OIDC or via a microservice?

Tags: oauth-2.0, keycloak, openid-connect

I have a setup like this:

1. Keycloak OIDC Server for Identity and Access Management Service - Running in Cloud - **A**
2. Backend RESTful Microservices - Running in Cloud - **B**
3. Backend RESTful Microservices - Running in On-prem servers across multiple locations - **C**
4. User Mobile app - Multiple users across locations - **X**
5. User web app - Multiple users across locations - **Y**

- **X, Y** uses **Password grant** to access **B**  - i.e. **X, Y** calls *login* *API* of **B** with *username* and *password*; **B** gets the access token from Keycloak and then sends it in response and they (X,Y) use it for further API calls towards **B** to get authorized.

**Now, this is the doubt that I have:**

- Should we do the same for **C**? i.e. Should there be an API in **B** available for **C** to call to post the *client-id* and *client-secret* (**client-credentials grant**), to get the access token? Is this a good pattern/ valid implementation?

**The need for this method of access:**

- Ops team is planning to hide **A** from being exposed to the internet. So, **B** will be acting as an abstraction layer for it.
- Is keeping the IAM service from being exposed to internet a good idea? I have never seen an IAM service, abstracted before. Please clarify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**HOSTING**

The usual hosting best practice is to place the Identity system behind a reverse proxy / gateway such as NGINX Plus. This is because the Identity system connects to sensitive data sources, whereas the reverse proxy can be the entry point, eg in a DMZ. You can then limit the OIDC endpoints exposed to the internet.

Avoid writing home grown proxying to the Identity system. since that is likely to be less resilient than a battle tested system such as NGINX. See the [IAM Primer](https://curity.io/resources/learn/iam-primer/) for an overview.

**SECURITY DESIGN PATTERNS**

A reverse proxy also supports plugins that can do many utility security jobs, such as translating secure cookies to access tokens. So it is a highly useful part of the architecture. See [this article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/integration-openresty/) for an example plugin using the high level LUA programming language.